# Prequel to First Men in the Moon?

Tags: h.g.wells, prequels

In the first chapter of *First Men in the Moon*, Wells writes:

> And this book is the sequel.

The Wikipedia page for *First Men* says it is preceded by *Love and Mr Lewisham*, however, the plot of *Love* doesn't seem to have anything to do with *First Men*.

Is there prequel to *First Men* or am I misreading the text?

Comment: Migrate to english.stackexchange.com? This is barely on topic here although it is a great question.

Comment: It's a question asking for clarification on the plot of a Sci Fi novel. I'd say it's on topic.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/23851/5450

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The full context is (from [Project Gutenburg](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1013/pg1013-images.html)):

> As I sit down to write here amidst the shadows of vine-leaves under the blue sky of southern Italy, it comes to me with a certain quality of astonishment that my participation in these amazing adventures of Mr. Cavor was, after all, the outcome of the purest accident. It might have been any one. I fell into these things at a time when I thought myself removed from the slightest possibility of disturbing experiences. I had gone to Lympne because I had imagined it the most uneventful place in the world. "Here, at any rate," said I, "I shall find peace and a chance to work!"
>
> And this book is the sequel.

A [secondary definition of the word “sequel” is “a result, consequence, or inference.”](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sequel) The narrator is effectively saying “I had an adventure. This book is the result.”